# gradle-sync error "No variants found for ':app'. Check build files to ensure at least one variant exists"

Tags: react-native, android-studio, build.gradle

I am updating the react version to 0.63.4 -> 0.72.1 by referring to the react upgrade helper.

After changing the source, the error "No variables found for ':app'. Check build files to enhance at least one variable exists" occurs at the time of grande sync.

- android/build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "33.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        targetSdkVersion = 33
        kotlin_version = '1.6.20'

        ndkVersion = "23.1.7779620"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle")
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version")
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle'
    }
}
```

- android/app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply from: project(':react-native-config').projectDir.getPath() + "/dotenv.gradle"
apply plugin: "kotlin-android"
apply plugin: "kotlin-parcelize"
apply plugin: "com.facebook.react"
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-code-push/android/codepush.gradle"

def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false
def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'

android {
    ndkVersion rootProject.ext.ndkVersion

    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    namespace "com.adb.bob"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.adb.bob"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 11
        versionName "1.2.1"
        multiDexEnabled true
        resValue "string", "build_config_package", "com.adb.bob"
        resValue 'string', "CODE_PUSH_APK_BUILD_TIME", String.format("\"%d\"", System.currentTimeMillis())
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty("BOB_RELEASE_STORE_FILE")) {
                storeFile file(BOB_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword BOB_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias BOB_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword BOB_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
            resValue "string", "CodePushDeploymentKey", CODEPUSH_DEPLOYMENT_KEY_DEBUG
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            matchingFallbacks = ['release']
            resValue "string", "CodePushDeploymentKey", CODEPUSH_DEPLOYMENT_KEY_PRODUCTION
        }
        devDebug {
            initWith debug
            applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
            matchingFallbacks = ['debug']
        }
        productionRelease {
            initWith release
            applicationIdSuffix ""
            matchingFallbacks = ['release']
        }
        releaseStaging {
            initWith release
            resValue "string", "CodePushDeploymentKey", CODEPUSH_DEPLOYMENT_KEY_STAGING
            matchingFallbacks = ['release']
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation("com.facebook.react:react-android")
    implementation project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}")

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.squareup.okhttp3', module:'okhttp'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}")
    
    if (hermesEnabled.toBoolean()) {
        implementation("com.facebook.react:hermes-android")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
```

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }

        exclusiveContent {
            // We get React Native's Android binaries exclusively through npm,
            // from a local Maven repo inside node_modules/react-native/.
            // (The use of exclusiveContent prevents looking elsewhere like Maven Central
            // and potentially getting a wrong version.)
            filter {
                includeGroup "com.facebook.react"
            }
            forRepository {
                maven {
                    url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

if add that part to Android/build.gradle, it becomes a gradle sync
What's the problem